# How to use ASP.NET Membership for User Defined Permissions

Tags: asp.net

I have a simple ASP.NET MVC 3 application. I have the database I designed for the application, which corresponds to a domain model (in an App.Domain assembly).
I auto-generated the Application Services Membership tables and added them to the application database. Membership creation is working fine.
I created a 'Permission' table which has a composite PK made up of UserId (from the auto-generated aspnet_Users table) and ContentId (from the Content table holding the application content).
The idea is to allow users to allocate permissions to other users for the content they create.
My plan is to then place logic in the Controllers that goes something like:
Collapse | Copy Code

```
Guid currentUser = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
int[] accessible = (from p in context.Permissions
                         where p.UserId == currentUser
                         select p.ContentId).toArray();
```

Then to get the content for the current user, something like this:
Collapse | Copy Code

```
IEnumerable<content> content = context.Content
            .Where(x => x.PublicAccess < 3 
            || accessible.Contains(x.ContentId));</content>
```

If I have made any sense, can anyone tell me if this is a normal way to handle user defined permissions.
Also, this code doesn't work because it won't cast the linq to an int[]. Any help with that?

Comment: What do you mean by "user-defined" permissions.  "user-defined" typically means that the user themselves defined it, and that doesn't make much sense with the word "permissions", which are usually something that an administrator manages.

Comment: I mean that a user can define permissions for other users. So any user can produce content that goes in the content table and then issue permissions to the other users that I want to give access to.

Comment: @Mystere Man- Thanks. Code is now working. I would vote your answer up but I don't have enough status points. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically permissions are handled by the role subystem.  You do something like this:

```
if (User.IsInRole("RoleName")) {
   DoWhateverTheUserIsAllowedToDo();
}
```

You can combine this with dynamically assigned content permissions by looking up what roles or users are assigned to the content, and checking if the user is in that role, or if the users is specifically allowed.

Role based permission scales better than assigning users to specific pages.  As the number of pages grow, assigning users to pages becomes a nightmare.  So you typically assign roles to pages, then assign users to roles.

Your code seems to want to do a lot of work, returning lots of different content items.  Typically, you know what item you want to control access to.  So you might do something like:

```
var roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser()
var content = from p in context.Permissions where p.ContentID == contentID 
                      && roles.Any(x => p.Roles.Contains(x)) select p;
```

But, there are so many ways to do this, you will have decide what works best for you.

I don't understand your last bit about not casting to an int[].  I assume `.toArray()` is a typo, it should be `.ToArray()`.  And if `ContentID` is an `int`, `.ToArray` should create an `int[]`.

Comment: I want users to be able to issue permissions to other users for the content they create. With roles I would have to create two unique roles (read, write) for each piece of content and then allow users to assign other users to the roles they created. Is this feasible?

Comment: @david004 - Well, it's certainly possible.  Your app could create a set of roles for each user, then let them add and remove users from each role.  But my guess is that you want users to specify access per page (or content item) rather than just access all their content?  Or is it enough to say that user a can see all of user b's content if they are in the allow role?  If you need granular control, then your orignal solution seems like it would be fine.  Just understand that managing this could be a nightmare.

Comment: Thank you, yes I am after the granular control. Noted that it could be a nightmare.